# casting values from an array to the findViewById ids

Tags: java, android

```
public String getTexts(int i, int j, String[][] setTexts){
    String id = new String();
    return id = setTexts[i][j];
}
    for (int i = 0; i < weights.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < weights[i].length; j++) {
            final EditText setTexts[i][j] = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getTexts(i,j,setTexts[][]));
        }
    }
```

I used a getter to get a value from a 2d array called "setTexts" that I created before the shown code, containing the ids of the EditTexts that I wanted to change. Then when I tried to use the method to get the ids, I get "unexpected tokens" and a "cannot resolve method "getTexts". I also tried casting but it didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Error** -  you need to pass `setTexts` not `setTexts[][]`, since the method is expecting a 2d String array. `setTexts[][]` is invalid argument

```
final EditText setTexts[i][j] = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getTexts(i,j,setTexts));
```

**Side Note:**

In the method `getTexts`, if you only wish to use `setTexts[i][j]`, then the method only can accept `String`. 3 arguments seems redundant.

```
public String getTexts(String s){
    String id = s;
    return id;
}
```

You can calculate the same thing while passing argument to the method

```
final EditText setTexts[i][j] = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.getTexts(setTexts[i][j]));
```